# I'm unable to understand how it is returning the below list. Please explain

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, indexing

`gift_costs` is a numpy array

```
with open('gift_costs.txt') as f:
    gift_costs = f.read().split('\n')
    
gift_costs = np.array(gift_costs).astype(int)  # convert string to int
```

`print(gift_costs)` returns `[ 8 84 42 ..., 59 12 12]`

`print(gift_costs < 25)` returns boolean list `[ True False False ..., False  True  True]`

Then, how are we getting another list-

`print(gift_costs[gift_costs < 25])` returns `[ 8 23 22 ..., 18 12 12]`

I understand that it is returning the list of gifts having cost < 25, but how?

Comment: Can you please provide the code? Also, is gift_costs a list or a numpy array?

Comment: It is a numpy array.

Comment: Some basic `numpy` reading should show you that arrays can be indexed with scalars, slices, lists/arrays of numbers, and list/arrays of booleans (T/F).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and as far as I have tested, it does not work with typical python lists.

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[l < 3]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

You might be using a numpy array, which supports these types of queries

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> print(l < 3)
[ True  True False False False]

>>> print(l[l < 3])
[1 2]
```

**Edit:**

Comparing a numpy array with a number returns a boolean array with each of the elements compared with the number.

For example:

```py
>>> l = np.array([1, 4, 3, 2, 5])
>>> l < 3
Output:        [ True False False  True False]
Comparisions:    1<3   4<3   3<3   2<3   5<3
```

And indexing a numpy array with a boolean array returns a new array with the indices whose equivalent indices in the boolean array are `True`

```py
l        =    [  1     4      3    2     5   ]
bool_arr =    [ True  False False True False ]
l[bool_arr] = [  1                 2         ]
```

The indices where there is a `True` in `bool_arr` are included in the new array, and the other indices are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

*Numpy* array class overloads various operators (including "<").

When you apply this operator to a *Numpy* array, the result is also
a *Numpy* array, of *bool* type, with elements equal to the result
of the above comparison.

And `gift_costs[gift_costs < 25]` is an example of **boolean indexing**,
where the index expression is just a list of *bool* and the result
is a "filtered" array, containing only elements, for which the
index expression was *True*.